# Javascript to select this checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

What would be a javascript to select this checkbox based on the value mbbadmin?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" style="display:none" value="mbbadmin">
```

Say if i had a different value `value="john"` is there a javascript i can enter in my browsers console to just select that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the correct code is

`$('input[value="mbbadmin"]').click()`

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP....

Comment: It worked for me how so?

Comment: Because the answer does not match the question at all @sonic.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.querySelector` and a CSS attribute selector:

```
var box = document.querySelector('[value="mbbadmin"]');
```

If you’re actually doing this as part of your application and not just for debugging convenience, though, it’s probably better to use `id`s (for example).

Comment: Its not selecting it for me. Perhaps its not supported?

Comment: @sonicboom what browser are you using?

Comment: @sonicboom: Where are you trying to select it?

Comment: Ah i figured it out! Its `$('input[value="mbbadmin"]').click()
`

Comment: Ummmm.... that is jQuery @sonicboom ...

Comment: @sonicboom: It should work without the `input`, for what it’s worth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can select the input based on the value attribute. If you give it an id of mbbadmin you could just do:

```
document.getElementById("mbbadmin").checked=true
```

Edit - learn something every day! Didn't know about querySelector. Cool!

Comment: Well im doing it by value not id